# Is it possible to modify the bits of a float?

Tags: binary, floating-point, computer-science, bit

I'm wondering if there is a way to get the value of the mantissa or the value of the exponent and modify them in order to create a new float variable, for example say I want a float to have exponent 10000100 and mantissa 00000110111101011100001, if I'd wanted to make a program that tells me what value is, is there something already built ?

like this

```
float = buildFloat(sign, exponent, mantissa)
float = buildFloat(0, 132, 228065) // example above = 32.87
```

On any lenguge less binary, preference C++ or Java

Comment: Which programming language(s) ?

Comment: Any language less binary, preference Java or C++, ruby Python

Comment: For C++, you can use the standard functions `copysign()`, `ldexp()`, `signbit()`, and `frexp()` to manipulate floating-point operands. These are in `<cmath>`.This may be more indirect control than you desire. If you know the details of the underlying floating-point representation (C++ does not prescribe any particular one, but these days likely IEEE-754 `binary32` and `binary64`), you can copy the data to an appropriately sized integer with `memcpy()` and manipulate the bits as you please, then copy the modified data back to a floating-point operand.

Comment: OMG thanks a lot really!! I'm going to check the doc of this functions but do you know any other good site to learn them well?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the memcpy () function, If you have time, could you explain it to me?